# Как динамически задать ширину DOM элемента Angular

Tags: css, angular

Делаю небольшой аналог Trello (учебный проект). Есть 2 DOM элемента: button и input.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<button class="board-title">{{ board?.title }}</button>
<input *ngIf="true" class="board-title inp" type="text" value="{{ board?.title }}">
```

Возник вопрос. Как лучше сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку (button), input становился такой же ширины как и кнопка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  setWidth(btn,inp) {
    inp.style.width =  btn.offsetWidth + "px";
  }
}
```

html:

```
<button style="margin:4px;" #btn  (click)=setWidth(btn,inp);>Click me</button>
<input style="margin:4px;" type="text" #inp />
```

Comment: Только необходимо указать тип
setWidth(btn:HTMLDivElement , inp:HTMLDivElement) {
    inp.style.width =  btn.offsetWidth + "px";
  }

Answer (score -1):

**Вариант от @Виталий Шебаниц категорически неприемлен**

Почему? Потому, что:
1. Вызов функции будет происходить слишком часто (убедитесь в этом, поставив туда console.log() и наблюдайте консоль.
2. Это неверный путь взаимодействия с DOM.

### Как же сделать **верно?**

```
@ViewChild('btn', {static: true}) element: ElementRef;

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.renderer.setStyle(this.element.nativeElement, 'width', 'УКАЖИТЕ ЗДЕСЬ ЖЕЛАЕМОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ');
}
```

Будут вопросы, пишите, отвечу.

Comment: Вариант от @Виталий Шебаниц приемлемен и правильный. Как вызов функции может происходить слишком часто на `click` ?? Ты сам так решил, что это неверный путь взаимодействия с DOM? Вопрос звучит `Как лучше сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку (button)` - а причем тут `ngOnInit`? Извини чувак, ставлю минус...

Comment: @overthesanity Ок, клик тут реально не причем. Вероятно, я этого не заметил. По второму пункту - это уже твои комплексы бога, очевидно, что нужно делать изменения через renderer2. Это не я так решил, это все Google со своим Angular и ShadowDOM, который дает тебе ElementRef для корректной работы с DOM. 

Ой, погоди, рассказать, почему плохо напрямую DOM трогать?

Comment: после фразы "комплексы бога" дальше читать не стал. Это у тебя изначально неправильный подход, который начинается с фразы "Вариант от @Виталий Шебаниц категорически неприемлен", который мне не понравился, потому что автор вопроса уже пометил его галочкой. Добра тебе и не воспринимай все в штыки :) Минус означает "ответ не является полезным", так вот, дружище, этот ответ не является полезным ибо он вовсе не помогает автору решить его вопрос. Если я в чем-то не прав, то упрекни меня в этом, я извинюсь и возьму свои слова обратно. 

Comment: @overthesanity и ты извини, если зацепил, однако, прочесть имеет смысл - я считаю, что прав в части использования renderer вместо того, как использовал Виталий. А основываться на галочке - это странно.

Comment: использованием renderer'а ты создаешь ненужный слой абстракции. Автор вопроса делает учебный проект, вариант от Виталия просто и понятен. Рендер2 нужен в том случае, когда ты разрабатываешь приложение, которое компилиритуется/выполняется в разных средах, а именно - `environments that don't have DOM access, like on the server, in a web worker or on native mobile`. Я на 200% уверен, что автор вопроса еще понятия не имеет что это такое.